# How to change order of plots within one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Here you can see a cutout of my code.

```
ratiox = seq(0, 3, 0.05)
x = rnorm(61, 55000, 3)
y1 = rep(200, times = 61)

l = cbind(ratiox, x, y1)
l = as.data.frame(l)
l$y1 = as.character(l$y1)

y1 = rep(100, times = 61)

m = cbind(ratiox, x, y1)
m = as.data.frame(m)
m$y1 = as.character(m$y1)

y1 = rep(50, times = 61)
n = cbind(ratiox, x, y1)
n = as.data.frame(n)
n$y1 = as.character(n$y1)

y1 = rep(25, times = 61)

o = cbind(ratiox, x, y1)
o = as.data.frame(o)
o$y1 = as.character(o$y1)

total = rbind(l,m,n,o)
View(total)

ggplot(total, aes(x = ratiox, y = y1, height = x/100000, fill = y1)) + 
  geom_ridgeline() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "gray", "lightblue", "red", "blue", "black")) + xlab("Emission ratio") + 
  ylab("") + theme_classic(base_size = 25)
```

In the end the order of the graphs does not meet my expectations. I would like that the order of the various concentrations (y1) corresponds to the order of the input. Meaning: 200, 100, 50 and 25. I would like that my variable y1 stays a character. I do not want to convert it into a numeric variable.

Comment: Quick suggestion on the *minimal* part of [mcve]: we don't need the code that goes through all these steps of creating data. You can post just the output of `dput` on the data you're plotting, and spare the question about 25 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your `y1` variable as a factor, and order the levels as desired.

`total$y1 <- factor(total$y1, levels = c("200", "100", "50", "25"))`